# Python Tkinter AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I have a problem using `tkinter` canvas object. The problem lies in the following function, and more precisely in `self.canvas.destroy()`. When i comment out the `try`-statement the function works perfectly for about 10000 cycles, then tkinter stops working altogether, which I suspect has to do with memory errors from not deleting the canvas object.

```
def updateFrame(self):
    self.canvas.pack_forget()
    try:
        self.canvas.destroy()
    except:
        pass
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width = 640, height = 640, bg = 'black')    
    for player in self.players:
        player.drawMaster()
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.canvas.after(10, self.updateFrame)
```

However, the error message I get when `self.canvas.destroy()` is active comes after two cycles.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1442, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 504, in callit
    self.deletecommand(name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 363, in deletecommand
    self._tclCommands.remove(name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

I really can't seem to find an answer. And to avoid solutions that I've already thought about: `self.canvas` is declared before the first run of the function, and is then only modified in the function above, so `self.canvas` is always a canvas object.

I'm also using threading, but don't know how this would affect the canvas object.

Edit:
The reason why I want to delete and create the canvas object between each frame is because i want the program to read the state of an underlying object and simply display it on the screen, and deleting the canvas object would be much easier than deleting every object on screen to redraw them.

Comment: why do you keep destroying and recreating the canvas every 10ms? That seems extremely inefficient and resource intensive. Are you aware you can erase the canvas with a single function call?

Comment: Which function erases the canvas? That might be the answer to my question. Edit: Found the function! You're a life saver

Comment: The `delete` method of the canvas. You can give it the special id `"all"` to delete everything in one call.

Comment: Threading is definitely the problem if you are manipulating widgets from more than one thread.